# Display Database of relational database records using hyperlink on JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am basically displaying MySQL database records on JSP/JSTL page using Servlet & JDBC. I have two tables one is "Employee Table" & other "Location Table"(both tables are related via PK & FK). Now I am able to display Employee Table on JSP which looks like:

[Employee Table on JSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl4bG.png)

Now the hyperlink is appearing on the column "Department #" that is supposed to display the "Location Table" for each employee, not all rows of different employees. My coding for this project includes **2 POJO classes for Employee & Location table, an EmployeeDbUtil class for JDBC connection, Employee Servlet and two JSP files for Employee & Location table display**.

[Location Table for single Employee when clicked on hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e377g.png)

Now what my problem is that I have hard coded the SQL query part on DbUtil class for getting the single row for Location Table by saying *"where location.dept_no = 10"* that's why it gives same row when clicked on any of the hyperlinks, this is not good. So please show me code segment that I can use such that I can get different results when clicked on different hyperlinks for different employees. I really don't know how to do that so please help me here. Thank you!

Here's my complete code (DbUtil, Servlet & JSP):

**EMPLOYEE DbUtil(For JDBC Connection)**

```
private DataSource dataSource;

    public EmployeeDbUtil(DataSource theDataSource) {

        dataSource = theDataSource;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployee() throws Exception {

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {

            // Get connection

            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            // SQL Query

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM order_customer.employee; ";

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (myRs.next()) {

                // retrieving data
                String employeeID = myRs.getString("employee_id");
                String name = myRs.getString("name");
                int salary = myRs.getInt("salary");
                String hireDate = myRs.getString("hire_date");
                int deptNum = myRs.getInt("dept_no");

                // create new customer object

                Employee tempEmployee = new Employee(employeeID, name, salary, hireDate, deptNum);

                // Now add tempCustomer to the ArrayList

                employees.add(tempEmployee);
            }

            return employees;
        }

        finally {
            close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
        }
    }

    private void close(Connection myConn, Statement myStmt, ResultSet myRs) {

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public List<Location> getLocation() throws Exception {

        List<Location> location = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {

            // Get connection

            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            // SQL Query

            String sql = "SELECT location.dept_no,location.state,location.city \r\n" + 
                    "from order_customer.employee JOIN order_customer.location\r\n" + 
                    "on employee.dept_no=location.dept_no\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE location.dept_no = '10' ";

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (myRs.next()) {

                // retrieving data

                int deptNum = myRs.getInt("dept_no");
                String state = myRs.getString("state");
                String city = myRs.getString("city");

                // create new customer object

                Location tempLocation = new Location(deptNum, state, city);

                location.add(tempLocation);
            }

            return location;
        }

        finally {
            close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
        }
    }
}
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
 private EmployeeDbUtil employeeDbUtil;

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/order_customer")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        try {
            employeeDbUtil = new EmployeeDbUtil(dataSource);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            // read the "command" parameter
            String theCommand = request.getParameter("command");

            if (theCommand == null) {
                theCommand = "LIST";
            }

            // route to the appropriate method
            switch (theCommand) {

            case "LIST":
                listEmployee(request, response);
                break;

            case "LOAD":
                loadLocation(request, response);
                break;

            default:
                listEmployee(request, response);
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {

            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
    }

    private void loadLocation(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        List<Location> location = employeeDbUtil.getLocation();

        request.setAttribute("THE_LOCATION", location);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/location-info.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    private void listEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        List<Employee> employees = employeeDbUtil.getEmployee();

        request.setAttribute("EMPLOYEE_LIST", employees);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/list-employee.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**JSP PAGE CODE:**

```
<
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Details</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">

            <table>

                <tr>

                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Hire Date</th>
                    <th>Department #</th>

                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="tempEmployee" items="${EMPLOYEE_LIST}">

                    <c:url var="employeeLink" value="EmployeeServlet">
                        <c:param name="command" value="LOAD" />
                        <c:param name="deptNum" value="${tempEmployee.deptNum}" />
                    </c:url>

                    <tr>
                        <td>${tempEmployee.employeeID}</td>
                        <td>${tempEmployee.name}</td>
                        <td>${tempEmployee.salary}</td>
                        <td>${tempEmployee.hireDate}</td>
                        <td> <a href= "${employeeLink}"> ${tempEmployee.deptNum} </a></td>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**JSP for Location table:**

```
<<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Employee Department</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Department Details</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="content">

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <th>Department #</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>City</th>

                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="tempLocation" items="${THE_LOCATION}">

                    <tr>
                        <td>${tempLocation.deptNum}</td>
                        <td>${tempLocation.state}</td>
                        <td>${tempLocation.city}</td>
                        <%--    <td> ${tempLocation.name} </td> --%>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "deptNum" parameter by the same way you do with "command", pass it to DBUtil and then replace the '10'

Comment: Could please you show me the code segment of that part, please!!